# PHP HTML/PHP to PDF file

Tags: php, pdf

I have an order acknowledgement template written in HTML/PHP.

How can I generate order acknowledgement PDFs in this case?

I have an idea of how I need to do it but don't quite know how or even what to search for to be able to carry it out which makes it a little harder.

```
$orders = array(
  '900101',
  '900102',
  '900103',
  '900104'
);

foreach ($order as $id) {
  // I need to visit oa_template.php?id=$id and save the contents as a PDF,
  // but I don't quite understand the simplest method to do so.
  //
  // contents of oa_template.php?id=$id -> $id.pdf
}
```

Any examples of the simplest method to do so would be great, or even a pointer to what functions in PHP etc. I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: dirt-simplest-and-probably-won't-work-anyways: `file_put_contents(file_get_contents("http://example.com/oa_template.php?id=$id", "$id.pdf"));`

Comment: DomPDF, mPDF, tcPDF... there's plenty of libraries out there to help do this if you just google for them

Answer (score 2):

There are two very good commercial APIs for this, both operated by my company (disclosure!).

Have a look at the documentation here:

- [HTML to PDF SDK in PHP](http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk/html-to-pdf-sdk) (htm2pdf)
- [HTML to PDF API](http://pdfmyurl.com/html-to-pdf-api) with PHP examples (pdfmyurl)

You should find plenty of examples on those pages. Basically you just pass the URL or the raw HTML and you get a PDF in return.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this library, it's pretty good, although you have to spend some time knowing how the basics works.

http://www.tcpdf.org/

examples here

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php

some of them are really good with a lot of stuff that maybe you will not use , but check it out.

Comment: Thanks. What's the most simplest way to just make a PDF of given URL?